# Problem Interpreting histogram

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am reading [Understandable statistics](https://www.cengage.com/c/understandable-statistics-concepts-and-methods-12e-brase/9781337119917PF/).

In the second chapter, example 2, the author shows the following histogram:

[image: Er]

The author then proceed to interpret the histogram as follows:

> About 40% of the wait times fall between 7 and 9 minutes
>   while about 80% are between 4 and 9 minutes. **Less than 1%
>   are 3 minutes or less or greater than 12**.

I think that the statement:

> Less than 1%
>   are 3 minutes or less or greater than 12

is false. It should be:

> Less than 10%
>   are 3 minutes or less or greater than 12

Is the author correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, looking at the graph, $10\%$ seems much more reasonable than $1\%$. It must have been a typo.